# How to build File Uri without newing a file?

Tags: android

I need to build a `Uri` object from a file path, but using `Uri.fromFile(new File(path))` is too slow, so I want to build it manually.

First of all, `Uri.parse("file://" + path)` does not work, since it does not path-encode the path.

I tried `Uri.Builder().scheme("file").path(orgPath).build()`, but the result is: `file:path` instead of `file://path`.

How can I build a `Uri` as same as `Uri.fromFile()` does, in a faster way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `Uri.encode()`

```
"file://"+Uri.encode(path)
```

**or if you want to allow the string like / or any other than pass it as second parameter**

**like :**

```
  "file://" + Uri.encode(path,"/")
```

Comment: Uri.encode() encodes everything including /, which is different from path encoding.

Answer (score 2):

OK I find out I just need to add `.auth()`.
`Uri.Builder().scheme("file").auth("").path(orgPath).build()` is working fine.